# Setting Parent Node In BST Insert

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have an insert function for my BST class and I'm trying to set the parent node, but I'm having a little bit of trouble. Here's my function:

```
void BST::insert_node(Play& play, BNode *&t){

    if( t == NULL)
        t = new BNode(play, t, NULL, NULL);

    else if( play < t->play){
        insert_node(play, t->left);

        if (height(t->left) - height(t->right) == 2){

            if( play < t->left->play)
                rotate_with_left_child(t);
            else
                double_rotate_with_left_child(t);

        }
    }
    else if( t->play < play){
        insert_node(play, t->right);

        if(height(t->right) - height(t->left) == 2){

            if( t->right->play < play)
                rotate_with_right_child(t);
            else
                double_rotate_with_right_child(t);

        }
    }
    else
        t->node_height = max(height( t->left ), height( t->right )) + 1;

}
```

Currently, all my node's parents are NULL. Can someone help me figure out how to correctly set the parent node?

This is my node struct:

```
struct BNode {
    Play play;
    BNode * parent;
    BNode * left;
    BNode * right;
    int times_searched;
    int node_height;
    BNode(Play p = Play(), BNode *par = NULL, BNode *lt = NULL, BNode *rt = NULL, int ts = 0, int nh = 0)
    : play(p), parent(par), left(lt), right(rt), times_searched(ts), node_height(nh) {}

};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
if( t == NULL)
        t = new BNode(play, t, NULL, NULL);
                            ^
```

Whenever any new node is allocated its parent is always NULL.

For 1st node inserted into the tree, the above is OK. However,when inserting into left  side or right side, you should check whether `t->left` or `t->right` are NULL. If NULL, allocate new node there itself.e.g.

```
else if( play < t->play){
        if(t->left == NULL)
        {
               t->left = new BNode(play, t, NULL, NULL);
        }
        else
        {
               insert_node(play, t->left);
        }
...
```

And, similarly, for right side insertion.